# Laravel - migration, table structure modification - correct way

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.8, laravel-migrations

My present table is

```
Schema::create('students', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('first_name', 255);
    $table->string('last_name', 255);
    $table->enum('gender', ['m', 'f']);
    $table->date('date_of_birth');
    $table->integer('roll_number');
    $table->char('section', 1);
    $table->integer('class');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('school_id');            
    $table->string('photo')->nullable;
    $table->timestamps();

    $table->foreign('school_id')
        ->references('id')->on('schools')
        ->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');

    $table->unique(['roll_number', 'section', 'class', 'school_id']);
});
```

Standards

```
Schema::create('standards', function (Blueprint $table) {
       $table->bigIncrements('id');
       $table->string('name');
       $table->unsignedBigInteger('school_id');
       $table->timestamps();

       $table->foreign('school_id')
       ->references('id')->on('schools')
       ->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
```

Sections

```
Schema::create('sections', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->char('name', 1);
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('standard_id');
    $table->timestamps();

    $table->foreign('standard_id')
    ->references('id')->on('standards')
    ->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

now I have standards and sections table and foreign keys from these tables will replace the class and section columns in existing structure and maintain the combination of `roll_number`, `section_id`, `standard_id` and `school_id` as unique.

I tried

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('students', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropUnique(['roll_number', 'section', 'class', 'school_id']);

            $table->dropColumn('section');
            $table->dropColumn('class');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('standard_id')->after('roll_number');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('section_id')->after('standard_id');

            $table->foreign('standard_id')->references('id')->on('standards')
            ->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('section_id')->references('id')->on('sections')
            ->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->unique(['roll_number', 'standard_id', 'section_id', 'school_id']); // unique combination
        });
    }
```

but it seems to be not working.

**Error**

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity
>   constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign
>   key constraint fails (`myapp_extra`.`#sql-2f78_29d`, CONSTRAINT
>   `students_standard_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`standard_id`) REFERE
>       NCES `standards` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE) (SQL: alter table `students` add constraint `students_standard_id_foreign`
>   foreign key (`standard_id`) references `standards` (`id`) on delete
>   cascade on update cascade)
>
> ```
>   at \myapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:664
> ```

**Note**: standards and sections table are created, before making this migration, so both columns are available.

Comment: What is the error you are getting ?

Comment: @SalmanZafar please reload, I have added the error.

Comment: Can you provide `sections` and `standards` schema?

Comment: @MiladBarazandeh please reload the page, I have just updated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Why this happens?

This error is occurring because you are inserting a new column without default value and without `NULLABLE` to your table that already has rows.

When you do it, MySQL will set it value to `0`, so all your tables will have `standard_id` and `section_id` set to `0`, so when you try to add your foreign index, it fails because `0` is not a valid id on your `standards`/`sections` table.

## So how to fix?

You have some ways to solve this issue:

### 1st: Setting a default value

If make sense for your application, you can set a default (valid) value to your column, so the foreign key won't fail:

```
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('standard_id')->default(1)->after('roll_number');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('section_id')->default(1)->after('standard_id');
```

Most times it's not so simple, so you will need to define the value dinamically

## 2nd: Setting the value dynamically

If you have some logic to set the default value for this new columns, you can break you migration into two steps:

```
// Add the fields first
Schema::table('students', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropUnique(['roll_number', 'section', 'class', 'school_id']);

        $table->dropColumn('section');
        $table->dropColumn('class');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('standard_id')->after('roll_number');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('section_id')->after('standard_id');
}

App\Students::get()->each(function($student) {
    // Apply your logic here
    $student->standard_id = 3;
    $student->section_id = 3;
    $student->save();
});

// Now you can add your foreign keys.
Schema::table('students', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreign('standard_id')->references('id')->on('standards')
        ->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('section_id')->references('id')->on('sections')
        ->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->unique(['roll_number', 'standard_id', 'section_id', 'school_id']); // unique combination
});
```

## 3rd: Make the field nullable

If you just don't know or don't have a default value for this fields, so your field should be nullable instead:

```
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('standard_id')->nullable()->after('roll_number');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('section_id')->nullable()->after('standard_id');
```

Comment: Thank you Elias, I was thinking how I can give existing standards' id or sections'id randomly, but it seems, just wanted not to write any insert queries in migration file, but seems, no other options.